# Efficiently concatenate array of arrays RDD by index of inner array

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I am using Databricks to run a Spark cluster (v3.0.1) using Scala (v2.12). I have Scala files compiled as JAR and I am running the job using `spark-submit` from Databricks UI.

The logic of the program starts with creating a list of random seeds and parallelizing it using the line:

```
val myListRdd = sc.parallelize(myList, partitions)
```

Next, I wish to run a processing function `f(...args)` on this RDD, with one of the `args` being the individual elements of `myListRdd`. The function has a return type of `Array[Array[Double]]`. So in Scala it would look like:

```
val result = myListRdd.map(f(_, ...<more-args>))
```

Now, I wish to efficiently collect the output array-of-arrays, using the following logic.

Example outputs from `f(...args)`:

```
Output 1: ((1.0, 1.1, 1.2), (1.3, 1.4, 1.5), ...)
Output 2: ((2.0, 2.1, 2.2), (2.3, 2.4, 2.5), ...)
Output 3: ((3.0, 3.1, 3.2), (3.3, 3.4, 3.5), ...)
... so on
```

Now, as these are the multiple outputs from `f(..args)`, I would like the final output using some spark RDD operations, to look like:

```
Type: Array[Array[Double]]
Value: ((1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 3.0, 3.1, 3.2, ...), (1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5, ...), ...)
```

I am new to Spark and Scala, so I am not able to map my logic to code. I attempted to use `flatMap` instead of `map` in above snippet, but it does not give me the output exactly I want. If I attempt to convert the output RDD to dataframe using `collect` operation, then it incurs lot of time in executing the job, and still I would need to run concatenate function over the dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have multiple instances of a type (in this case `Array[Array[Double]]`) and you need to combine them into a single instance of that type, then you probably want to `fold()` (or possibly `reduce()`).

```
List(output1,output2,output3)
  .foldLeft(Array.empty[Array[Double]]){
    case (acc, aad) => aad.indices.map{idx =>
      acc.lift(idx).fold(aad(idx))(_ ++ aad(idx))
    }.toArray
  }
//res0: Array[Array[Double]] =
// Array(Array(1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 3.0, 3.1, 3.2)
//     , Array(1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try reducing the output from your function to combine the arrays:

```scala
myListRdd.map(f(_, ...<more-args>))
         .reduce((x, y) => (0 to x.size - 1).toArray.map(i => x(i) ++ y(i)))
```